# Azure Function Blob Trigger Failing - Python

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have recently started reading about Azure Functions so decided to give it a go.

I created a test Azure Function in Visual Code using Python, which should fire off a trigger when a blob has been uploaded to the specified container but for some reason I am getting this error below:

```
2021-01-14T11:27:32Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.TestBlobTrigger' (Failed, Id=dfd0dd15-d937-486d-b6f3-1634745ff14d, Duration=37ms)
```

To provide more context, this is my `function.json` file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "root/test",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my `_init_.py` file:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

And finally this is my `local.settings.json` file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXX;AccountKey=XXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate any tips in order to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you solved the problem ?

Comment: nope had no luck as of yet

Comment: May I know if you already have a function app on azure portal and then deploy the local function to that function app ? Or when you deploy the local function, create the function app on azure portal at the same time ?

Comment: I already have everything set up, so the function app is already up and running and I have made a test function using a timer trigger and that works fine

Comment: So you deploy the local function code to a function app which already exists on portal ?

Comment: If you still not solve the problem, could you please enter your chat room with Frank ?

Comment: I did, he tried to help but it didn't get resolved

Comment: Please enter the chat room, we can talk there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the two `AzureWebJobsStorage`(in local and on portal) are different. When you deploy the function from local to azure, it will not upload the `AzureWebJobsStorage` in `local.settings.json` to the application settings of function on portal.

So the solution is copy the value of `AzureWebJobsStorage` in `local.settings.json` to replace `AzureWebJobsStorage` in application settings of function on portal.